# Go to a record on a split form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to go to the record which was just appended on a split form after requerying the form. the below code does not produce an error but it doesn't go to the new record either. All the parameters are correct. Any thoughts?

```
Forms!frmAddNewComponent.Requery
FindRecord Forms!frmAddNewComponent, Forms!frmAddNewComponent!txtID.Value, "ID"


Public Sub FindRecord(Component As Form, PK As Long, PKField As String)

    With Component.RecordsetClone
        .FindFirst PKField & "=" & PK
        If .NoMatch Then
            MsgBox "Record not found!", vbCritical
        Else
            Component.Bookmark = .Bookmark
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: hi. shouldnt Component be a recordset and not a Form ?

Comment: @LuisCurado I believe I need to set the bookmark of the `Form` object to the matching record in the `RecordsetClone` of the Form.

Comment: If PKField is the default sort column then surely you want find last not find first?

Comment: @HarassedDad PKField is the name of the Primary Key column. I want to find the first record where the PKField = PK.

Comment: What is value of PK? How is it set? What do you mean by 'first' record, there should only be one for each PK. Perhaps use DMax() to grab the latest PK. Edit question to show code that calls this procedure.

Comment: @June7 I am simply grabbing the ID value from the form after the record is appended. There is only one record for the PK so `FindFirst` should still work. I thought of `DMax` but I am not sure if that would interfere in a multi-user environment.

Comment: Step debug. What is value of PK variable when the procedure runs? Is it the PK you expect? You have to save the new PK somewhere before the requery so that you can reference it afterward. This means saving it to an unbound textbox or a global variable or TempVar.

Comment: You solved it for me!! The problem, as you said, was that I was requerying the form which showed the newly appended record. But it also selected the first record. THEN I grabbed the ID which is why it stayed there. I knew PK had the ID but somehow I didn't notice that it was the wrong one. Maybe it would have been easier to spot if I had reset the PK to 1. Thank you very much!